# How to use angular-in-memory-web-api in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-http

I have installed this package.

My mock data class:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InCredentialsService implements InMemoryDbService {

  public createDb() {

    const credentials = {
      auth: true,
      id: 1,
      token: 'token',
      grant: 'all'
    };

    return credentials;

  }
}
```

In `app.module.ts` I set dependence in `import` section:

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
```

Now I try to use that like this:

```
return this.http.get('api/credentials');
```

It returns me HTTP error:

> Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: api/credentials

How to use  angular-in-memory-web-api right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
return { credentials };
```

This is the short form for

```
return { credentials: credentials };
```

and the identifier becomes the API.